# Javascript validation of login form - field must be not blank and contain a "\"

Tags: javascript, validation

Here is the code I have now.

```
function ns_check()
{
    var login = document.forms['vpnForm'].login.value;
    var passwd = document.forms['vpnForm'].passwd.value;
    var domainname = login.indexOf("\\")

               if (domainname = - 1){

                              window.alert(_("You need to enter a domain name")); return false;  

               }
         if (login == ""){

                              window.alert(_("You need to enter login name")); return false; 

               }

               if (passwd == ""){

                              window.alert(_("You need to enter passwd")); return false; 

               }

               return true;

    }
```

When you do not use a backslash in the login box it does popup an alert window, but it is empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (domainname = - 1)
```

should be

```
if (domainname === - 1)
```

Comment: Even better: `if (domainname === -1)`

Comment: Is there a way to combine the username validation into one statement. For instance I would like to make sure there is a "\" and that the field is not blank. Any alert for the username field is just a blank alert.